# error: undeclared function

Tags: c, gtk

In my gtk+ application i have function in mainwin.c:

```
void
on_prev( GtkWidget* btn, MainWin* mw )
{
   ...
}
```

And in file ui.h i have:

```
#include "mainwin.h"
static const GtkActionEntry entries[] = {
    {
      "Go Back",
      GTK_STOCK_GO_BACK,
      "Go Back",
      "<control>b",
      "Go Back",
       G_CALLBACK(on_prev)
    },
}
```

But when i try to compile this application, i see error: **ui.h:error: 'on_prev' undeclared here (not in a function).**

What's wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add a prototype for it, probably in mainwin.h:

```
void
on_prev( GtkWidget* btn, MainWin* mw );
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I added prototype in mainwin.h, but it did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't have static data in a header. That means every time you include that file from a C file, you get a new, static (i.e. local to that C file) instance of the array. That is very likely not what you need.

Move the declaration and initialization of the array into a C file, and make sure the various functions it refers to are properly declared.